# Load .obj file and dependencies in three js

Tags: three.js

I have a zip that I fetch server side - from there I return a list of urls to the client. This list of file path contains an obj file, the textures, and material files. Is it possible to load these separately i to three js? I see a setPath method on the obj and mtl loaders but these files wont be in a directory so relative pathing won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager) to adjust the paths as needed:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.setURLModifier((url) => {
  return url.replace('/foo/', '/bar/');
});
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load( ... );
```

three.js r91